# Displays tags only for certain category in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, tags, custom-post-type

I currently have a custom post type, named Sectors. This has categories too.
[image: Sectors]

```
    add_action( 'init', 'wpsites_custom_post_type' );
function wpsites_custom_post_type() {

register_post_type( 'sectors',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'          => __( 'Sectors' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'sector' ),
        ),
        'has_archive'  => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_icon'    => 'dashicons-heart',
        'public'       => true,
        'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'sectors', 'with_front' => false ),
        'supports'     => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies'   => array( 'sectors', 'post_tag' ),
    ));

}
```

In here, I have individual sectors, which can have tags attatched
[image: Tags]

What I am currently trying to do, is add tags to a certain sector, and the tagged sector will be a 'featured sector' In its category page.

Using the code below, on my taxonomy-sectors.php page, I can do this:

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
      'tag_slug__and' => array('sector1'),
      'post_type' => array( 'sectors' )
      );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
     <?php echo "<div class='col-md-6' style='margin-bottom:20px;'>"; ?>
     <div class="row mobilemargin">
      <div class="categorytiletextsector1">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopr"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'categoryimage', array('class' => 'sector1img hovereffect')); ?> </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="testdiv">
           <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
           <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <?php echo "</div>"; ?>

 </a>
```

The Issue is, this displays these tagged sectors on EVERY category page, as all categories use the taxonomy page. Is there a way, that it would only display these tagged sector pages to its own category? No sectors can be in 1 category, if that helps.

Any help would be great, this has been bugging me for days now :(

EDIT

The code below is from an answer, but this does not return anything now, is there something missing??

```
$args = array(
    'tag_slug__and' => array( 'sector1' ),
    'post_type'     => array( 'sectors' ),
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
            'terms'    => get_queried_object_id(),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Isn't there a `cat` argument you can use in your `$args` array? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: I guess, but isn't this only when you choose which category you want. 
I mean, I want it to choose for me, as I can't say 'Category 4'.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have at the moment, as you've already found, will retrieve all posts and isn't specific to the term you're viewing.

If I've understood your question correctly you want to filter the posts shown to the term you're viewing. This can be done by getting the current term ID using `get_queried_object_id()` and passing it into a `tax_query` argument.

Change:

```
$args = array(
    'tag_slug__and' => array('sector1'),
    'post_type' => array( 'sectors' )
);
```

To:

```
$args = array(
    'tag_slug__and' => array( 'sector1' ),
    'post_type'     => array( 'sectors' ),
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
            'terms'    => get_queried_object_id(),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: For some reason, the tagged item doesn't show anywhere now?

Comment: Not on any category page at all now, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
   <div class="testdiv"> 
          <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5> 
          <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
          <p><?php the_tags( 'Tags: ', ', ', '<br />' ); ?></p> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies if this is daft, where do I add this?

Comment: Anyone? Not too sure where to execute this code, tried a few places but don't want to upvote if this doesnt work

Comment: If you want display tag with your post then use this code on taxonomy-sectors.php page.    `<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="testdiv">
           <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
           <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
           <p><?php the_tags( 'Tags: ', ', ', '<br />' ); ?></p>
         </div>
       </div>`

Comment: What is this suppose to do. Sorry, but this is crap.